# Server API and pages in same Express app?

Tags: node.js, express

I need to provide a set of API and some rendered page using Express.

Should I put API and pages in the same ExpressJS API?

This is my API example:

```
app.post("/pdf/create", function (req, res) {
    printPdf(req.template, req.data, “pdf-data/”, callback);
});
```

And this is the pag I need to provide:

```
app.get(“/”, function (req, res) {
    res.render(“index.tpl”, locals: { title: “Title”});
});
```

Is it the correct way or should I split them in two parts/files/modules?

Answer (score 1):

In the end, this is your choice, and can come down to opinion.  Initially when you construct your application, it might be easier to have all the code in a single file.  Doing so can become difficult to manage as the application grows, and as you add more developers (merge conflicts are more likely if you're editing the same file).  Also, if you test your source code, it can be easier to focus your efforts on smaller chunks of code.

So with that said, a popular approach is separating out the API endpoints into separate controllers responsible for a single function.  So perhaps you have some function responsible for PDFs, as in your example above.  This function could exist in a one controller, while your rendering of the index page could live in a separate controller.  These controllers are then both loaded up in your main application file, which is responsible for starting up the application.

As for if it makes sense to have an API that handles data and an endpoint which renders HTML in the same app, that's fine, unless they deal with very different functionality.  But if the render endpoint shows pages that end up sending data to your APIs, then that makes perfect sense to keep them in the same application.

It really depends on how much code you have in your app.  Generally it's a good practice to separate things out though to allow for future growth, but use your judgement.  Separating your logic into separate files/projects/etc is a balance that you probably need to play around with before you know for sure.  I'd recommend looking at other open source applications out there to see how others do it, and find out what makes sense to you.